# Eclipse e4: Accessing properties in PostContextCreate

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am using the `PostContextCreate` part of the life cycle in an e4 RCP application to create the back-end "business logic" part of my application. I then inject it into the context using an `IEclipseContext`. I now have a requirement to persist some business logic configuration options between executions of my application. I have some questions:

1. It looks like properties (e.g. accessible from `MContext`) would be really useful here, a straightforward `Map<String,String>` sounds ideal for my simple requirements, but how can I get them in `PostContextCreate`?
2. Will my properties persist if my application is being run with `clearPersistedState` set to `true`? (I'm guessing not).
3. If I turn `clearPersistedState` off then will it try and persist the other stuff that I injected into the context?

Or am I going about this all wrong? Any suggestions would be welcome. I may just give up and read/write my own properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `Map` returned by `MApplicationElement.getPersistedState()` is intended to be used for persistent data. This will be cleared by -clearPersistedState.

The PostContextCreate method of the life cycle is run quite early in the startup and not everything is available at this point. So you might have to wait for the app startup complete event (`UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE`) before accessing the persisted state data.

You can always use the traditional `Platform.getStateLocation(bundle)` to get a location in the workspace .metadata to store arbitrary data. This is not touched by clearPersistedState.

Update:

To subscribe to the app startup complete:

```
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextCreate(IEventBroker eventBroker)
{
  eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE, new AppStartupCompleteEventHandler());
}


private static final class AppStartupCompleteEventHandler implements EventHandler
{ 
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(final Event event)
  {
    ... your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @greg, that's great. I have a few more questions (sorry!): 1. How do I respond to the app startup complete event? Would I use `@Inject @Optional private void eventReceived(@UIEventTopic("UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE") String event)`? 2. Would my current life-cycle manager class be a good place to put that (as this doesn't really relate to a GUI element)? 3. I'm trying to get my head into the 'right' way to be doing stuff in e4, would you recommend the persisted state over the Platform.getStateLocation(bundle) solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if the @UIEventTopic code is set up at this point in the startup, I use the more 'traditional' subscribe method - see update to answer. Persisted state looks ok for small things, for large stuff use the state location (I have a database in the state location for one app).

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm going round in circles a bit. I tried what you suggested, but I seem to have the following issue: when I create my back-end I need to have access to configuration information, so on app startup complete sounds like a good idea; however, there are parts of the UI that use the back-end and rely on DI for it. When I tried to move the creation of the back-end to app startup complete my GUI failed to start as there was no back-end. What did I miss?

Comment: Sounds like the persisted state is going to be awkward to use for your case. Use data in the state location and do the set up in PostContextCreate. Other possibilities are ContextFunctions, AddOns and OSGi services.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll do that. Could you point me in the direction of some reading for your other possibilities? I struggle to find a good central reference point for e4.

Comment: Lars Vogel's e4 [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) is a good start (there is also a book based on this which has just had a second edition). He also has separate tutorials on [ContextFunction](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ContextFunctions/article.html) and [OSGi Services](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html)